# Xcode lost all frameworks after update to Snow Leopard: How to fix that?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

For some reason after updating to Snow Leopard, my Xcode 3.2 is stupid like a toast. I had all iPhone SDK's, tons of Gigabytes of data. All is gone to deep toilet. And now I start downloading all that stuff again. Is there maybe some little hope that all those SDK's are still on my mac, somewhere? Where? Or must I really re-download and re-install all this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the 3.1 final sdk, it has the 2.2.1 sdk in it. On disk it's usual location is: /Dwveloper/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk

Also included is 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: oh that's confusing, but you're right. I've downloaded the new SDK and it contains the old ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it's gone, just reinstall and it should be fine and dandy like sour candy

Comment: I totally stealing that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone SDK 2.2.0 and iPhoneSimulator SDK 2.2.1 are gone forever!